# haskell parsec newline before '}'

Tags: parsing, haskell, testing, ghc, parsec

Hi I am trying to parse a list of elements separated by the word and and in between curly brackets. the curly brackets and the "and"s could be surrounded by spaces or newlines. I wrote this parser:

```hs
testBodyP :: Parser [Tester.Condition]
testBodyP =
  Parsec.between
    (Parsec.char '{' <* Parsec.spaces)
    (Parsec.spaces *> Parsec.char '}')
    (Parsec.sepBy
       condtionP
       (Parsec.spaces *> Parsec.string "and" <* Parsec.spaces))
```

but the parser fails with this error:

```
unexpected "}"
expecting space or "and"
```

on this script:

```
("breaks", "echo -n does this test work") should {
        contain("byeeeee") and
        contain("nope")
}
```

but it does work on this script

```
("breaks", "echo -n does this test work") should {
        contain("byeeeee") and
        contain("nope")}
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks!

#### edit (response to Noughtmare):

it just calls other parses I defined so it would be ugly to put it here. If you want checkout the source code on my github: https://github.com/RHL120/sbt

#### edit:

I changed the testBodyP function on the github repo to and used spaces as a seprator. Now it "works"

Comment: I think we'll need to know what `conditionP` is to be able to answer this. I'm guessing this is due to the lack of backtracking and can be "fixed" with a `try` somewhere.

Comment: Why don't you just use `between` with only the brackets themselves, and only worry about the spaces when processing the contents?